# Why Apexaction flow setoutput variable not showing from apex class

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, error, visual-flows

I Want to set output values in flow  from apex action.

Below mentioned im getting oppId as input values from apex class.

```
public class flowinputs{
            @invocableVariable public String oppId;
           }
```

[image]

But Store Output Values not showing my apex results  class Quoteids, QuoteSums.

This sample pic from google Same(result in setoutputvalues) like this i want to see in my Action, in order to store the output value (in my case the Results are Quoteids,QuoteSums):
[image]

Please refer the below screenshot like this  i want.

See below image output values not showing from apex class result Quoteids, QuoteSums. In set ouput values i can't able to declare new resources also.
[image]

In Flow Debug im getting my results but im not able to assign output values
[image]

Here is apex code, Im getting results, I need to get setoutputvalues from apex as collection variable.

```
    public class checksum {
    public class flowinputs{
            @invocableVariable public String oppId;
           
    }
    public class results{
            @invocableVariable public Decimal Quotesum;
        public results(Decimal Quotesums){this.Quotesum=Quotesums;}
          @invocableVariable public string Quoteid;
        public results(string Quoteids){this.Quoteid=Quoteid;}
        
    }
@invocableMethod
    public static list<list<results>> countSum(list<flowinputs> requests){
        list<list<results>> usd =new list<list<results>>();
        list<results> ussd=new list<results>();
        usd.add(ussd);
        List<id> oppids = new list<Id>();       
        for(flowinputs request:requests)
        {
            oppids.add(request.oppId);
            
        }
        for(AggregateResult Qsum: [select SBQQ__Quote__r.id quoteid,SBQQ__Product__r.id prid,sum(SBQQ__Quantity__c) qunty from SBQQ__QuoteLine__c where SBQQ__Quote__r.id=: oppids group by SBQQ__Product__r.id,SBQQ__Quote__r.id]){
           String accid =(String)Qsum.get('quoteid');
            String acid =(String)Qsum.get('prid');
            Decimal quotesums=(Decimal)Qsum.get('qunty');
           // System.debug('accid' +accid);
            System.debug('sum'+quotesums);
            ussd.add(new results(quotesums));
              ussd.add(new results(acid));
            ussd.add(new results(accid));
        }
            
return usd;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Typo?  `public results(string Quoteids){this.Quoteid=Quoteid;}` You should also name your inner class `results` to `Result` as it contains only scalars, not collections

Comment: Look at the below link. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableVariable.htm

Your results class doesn't look the same as theirs, probably try to mimic that more closely? One thing I notice that seems important is after they @invocableVariable they have parenthesis around their definitions where you do not (in their second example). 
And then when they define the variable, they do it much more cleanly "public SObject outputMember" where you have extra stuff. Also it looks like you named both outputs "results"